# twisted conch, overriding authentication

Tags: python, ssh, twisted

I have been trying to override the default authentication scheme in a twisted conch module. Something that I thought I understood how to do. The script itself is the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195427/twisted-conch-filetransfer)
question. I am subclassing `SSHUserAuthClient` in the following way:

```
class ClientUserAuth(SSHUserAuthClient):
    def getPassword(self, prompt = None):
        return defer.succeed("*****")
```

and I am obviously replacing the `SSHUserAuthClient` call with a call to my class in the script. For reasons I can't understand the script is not executing the `getPassword` method in my class but the superclass `getPassword` method. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?
The only other change to the script I made is I added the following module import

```
from twisted.internet import defer
```

Thanks!

EDIT: Strangely the subclass method `getPublicKey` is being called correctly. It is just the `getPassword` method that is acting weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably actually seeing **keyboard-interactive** authentication taking place.  This is like password authentication, but separate.  The reason you see different behavior between Linux and OS X is just that your Linux and OS X SSH servers are configured differently.

Override `getGenericAnswers` to handle this one.

Comment: Well I am a moron. Your suggestion works perfectly...thanks again :)

Answer (score 3):

Some additional details of how to implement a keyboard-interactive authentication.

I thought I had this working the first time, but my server sends two interactive requests. The first requests contains a prompt = `[('Password: ', False)]`. 
The second contains an empty prompt = `[]`

The code below works with every server I've tested so far (Redhat, Ubuntu, OpenSUSE)

`from twisted.conch.ssh import keys, userauth`

```
class ClientUserAuth(userauth.SSHUserAuthClient):
    def getPassword(self, prompt = None):
        #normal password authentication
        print "PASSWORD AUTH"
        return defer.succeed('*****') # <-- YOUR PASSWORD

    def getGenericAnswers(self, name, instruction, prompts):
        #interactive password authentication
        print "INTERACTIVE AUTH"
        response = ['']*len(prompts)
        for i, p in enumerate(prompts):
            try:
                if('password' in p[0].lower()):
                    response[i] = '*****' # <-- YOUR PASSWORD
            except:
                pass
        #The response is always a sequence, and the length of it is always
        #identical to the length of prompts
        return defer.succeed(response)
```

Enabling Logging in Twisted was helpful for debugging what Conch was doing under the hood as well.

```
from twisted.python import log
log.msg('Started Logging for A Conch Program')
log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
```