# Python Twisted: twisted conch filetransfer verifyHostKey

Tags: python, twisted, sftp

I playing around with the sftp example from here: [Stackoverflow: twisted conch filetransfer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195427/twisted-conch-filetransfer/5205854#5205854)

I am using this here to connect. So I can use a key from a string instead of a password or the keys in ~/.shh. Now I want to deliver a hostkey or a fingerprint from a hostkey to avoid to prompt the user to verify the hostkey

```
def sftp(user, host, port, key, hostkey):
    options = ClientOptions()
    options['key'] = keys.Key.fromString(key.strip()).keyObject
    options['host'] = host
    options['port'] = port
    conn = SFTPConnection()
    conn._sftp = Deferred()
    auth = SSHUserAuthClient(user, options, conn)
    connect(host, port, options, verifyHostKey, auth)
    return conn._sftp
```

I tried to give some arguments to verifyHostkey, as you can read in it's [source](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/conch/client/default.py#L30) the param fingerprint is not used and I haven't found a valid value for transport.

```
def verifyHostKey(transport, host, pubKey, fingerprint):
     """        
     Verify a host's key.
     ....
```

Any ideas how I can omit the user to be prompted to verify a hostkey without writing the hostkey to ~/.shh/known_hosts?

Okay, I have wrote a function based on the answer of Jean-Paul Calderone. I is quite naive but does it job nice. The goal was to omit the need for an known-host file. I want all the keys only to live in memory.

```
def verifyHostKey(transport, host, pubKey, fingerprint):
    keytype, key = transport.factory.options['hostkey'].split(" ")[1:]
    hostkey = keytype + " " + key
    key = Key.fromString(hostkey)
    if key.fingerprint() == fingerprint:
       return succeed(True)
    else:
       raise BadKeyError
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried to give some arguments to verifyHostkey

Are you saying you tried calling `verifyHostKey` yourself?  It sounds like that's not going to help you avoid prompting the user for unknown host keys.  Instead, you want to pass a different function for that parameter to `connect`.  Instead of using the `verifyHostKey` function supplied by `twisted.conch.client.default`, use one something like this:

```
from twisted.internet.defer import succeed

def verifyHostKey(transport, host, pubKey, fingerprint):
    return succeed(True)
```

Or, if you want to implement your own checking, not just accept any host key, define a function that has that checking in it.  Return a Deferred, and if the check succeeds, fire that Deferred with True.  If the check fails, fire it with False.

Comment: Thanks, I just implemented my own function as you proposed. Working fine for me now.