# Script to ssh into server automatically

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, ssh

I'm trying to create a script to automatically log me in to a password protected server to upload a file from an ubuntu directory automatically. I am doing this for the purposes of automatically backing up a directory every hour. I already know had to add cron jobs to run my script every hour, but I don't know how to SSH, zip my directory then upload it. I don't know bash scripting very well, and in fact I was thinking it might be easier for me to use a python script. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

You absolutely need [public keys](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/ssh-public-key-based-authentication-how-to.html) instead of passwords. And using bash will be far easier than python. Simply `zip` your file and then `scp` it or `rsync` the whole dir.

Comment: +1 to that.  And if you're going to protect your ssh keys with passphrases (usually a good idea), you'll need to learn a bit about ssh agents to avoid having to enter a passphrase every hour.  The man page for ssh-agent is a good place to start.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with [Rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/documentation.html). It supports ssh tunneling and is a very good tool for backups.

Answer (score 1):

```
zip -R backup.zip directory && scp backup.zip username@server:destination_path
```

should do the job. As stated above, you should definitely use key authentication for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use "Twisted conch library"

Conch is an SSHv2 implementation written in Python.

- http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/conch/
- http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/conch/examples/

There is an example here:

- [twisted conch filetransfer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195427/twisted-conch-filetransfer)