# Use of the ISFTP interface of twisted conch to perform download and upload?

Tags: python, twisted.conch

I am working to program a SFTP client using twisted conch. I have found an example using the `FileTransferClient` class of twisted conch in this ([twisted conch filetransfer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195427/twisted-conch-filetransfer)).

The `openFile` method of this class return an Object that adheres to ISFTP server. This interface has methods to write and read: `readChunk` and `writeChunk`. But from this step I do not know how to use this interface and the `openFile` object to perform the file transfer.
I spent a week on this without success.

Can you give me an example using this `openFile` object?

Answer (score 1):

The following Channel subclass is lacking appropriate error handling but it may serve to get you started:

```
class SFTPChannel(channel.SSHChannel):
    name = 'session'

    def channelOpen(self, whatever):
        d = self.conn.sendRequest(self, 'subsystem', common.NS('sftp'), wantReply=True)
        d.addCallbacks(self._cbSFTP)

    def _cbSFTP(self, result):
        self.client = FileTransferClient()
        self.client.makeConnection(self)
        self.dataReceived = self.client.dataReceived


    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def send_file(self, path, data, mode=0700):
        ifile = yield self.client.openFile(path, FXF_WRITE | FXF_CREAT, dict(permissions=mode))
        yield ifile.writeChunk(0, data)


    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def get_file(self, local_path, remote_path, mode=0700):
        f = open(local_path, 'w')

        ifile = yield self.client.openFile(remote_path, FXF_READ, dict())

        n = 0

        try:
            while True:
                s = yield ifile.readChunk(n, 16 * 1024)
                n += len(s)
                f.write(s)
        except EOFError:
            pass

        f.close()
        os.chmod(local_path, mode)
```

Comment: Thank you for you response. In fact I have used the cftp script and adapte it with my project. I will try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os, sys, getpass, struct, stat
#import fnmatch, pwd, glob
import fnmatch, glob
#import os.path
from twisted.conch.client import connect, default, options
from twisted.conch.ssh import connection, common
from twisted.conch.ssh import channel, filetransfer
from twisted.protocols import basic
from twisted.internet import reactor, stdio, defer, utils
from twisted.python import log, usage, failure
#from Lib.ntpath import _abspath_split




#==================================A Class from cftp for the sftp subsystem invokation================
"""
I take It from the cftp lib because there is windows unsuported import in that package
THis import is simply to simplify the invokation of the sftp subsytem
"""
class ClientOptions(options.ConchOptions):

    synopsis = """Usage:   cftp [options] [user@]host
         cftp [options] [user@]host[:dir[/]]
         cftp [options] [user@]host[:file [localfile]]
"""
    longdesc = ("cftp is a client for logging into a remote machine and "
                "executing commands to send and receive file information")

    optParameters = [
                    ['buffersize', 'B', 32768, 'Size of the buffer to use for sending/receiving.'],
                    ['batchfile', 'b', None, 'File to read commands from, or \'-\' for stdin.'],
                    ['requests', 'R', 5, 'Number of requests to make before waiting for a reply.'],
                    ['subsystem', 's', 'sftp', 'Subsystem/server program to connect to.']]

    compData = usage.Completions(
        descriptions={
            "buffersize": "Size of send/receive buffer (default: 32768)"},
        extraActions=[usage.CompleteUserAtHost(),
                      usage.CompleteFiles(descr="local file")])

    def parseArgs(self, host, localPath=None):
        self['remotePath'] = ''
        if ':' in host:
            host, self['remotePath'] = host.split(':', 1)
            self['remotePath'].rstrip('/')
        self['host'] = host
        self['localPath'] = localPath






class my_sftpLib(object):

    ps = 'm_sftpLib> '
    delimiter = '\n'

    def __init__(self, client, f = None):
        self.client = client
        self.currentDirectory = ''
        self.file = f
        self.bufSize = 32768
        self.Nrequest = 5

    def _ebCloseLf(self, f, lf):
        lf.close()
        return f

    def _cbGetOpenFile(self, rf, lf):
        return rf.getAttrs().addCallback(self._cbGetFileSize, rf, lf)

    #---------------------------------------------------------------
    def _cbSetCurDir(self, path):
        self.currentDirectory = path
        self._newLine()

    def _newLine(self):
        if self.client.transport.localClosed:
            return
        self.transport.write(self.ps)
        self.ignoreErrors = 0
        if self.file:
            l = self.file.readline()
            if not l:
                self.client.transport.loseConnection()
            else:
                self.transport.write(l)
                self.lineReceived(l.strip())



    def _getFilename(self, line):
        line.lstrip()
        if not line:
            return None, ''
        if line[0] in '\'"':
            ret = []
            line = list(line)
            try:
                for i in range(1,len(line)):
                    c = line[i]
                    if c == line[0]:
                        return ''.join(ret), ''.join(line[i+1:]).lstrip()
                    elif c == '\\': # quoted character
                        del line[i]
                        if line[i] not in '\'"\\':
                            raise IndexError, "bad quote: \\%s" % line[i]
                        ret.append(line[i])
                    else:
                        ret.append(line[i])
            except IndexError:
                raise IndexError, "unterminated quote"
        ret = line.split(None, 1)
        if len(ret) == 1:
            return ret[0], ''
        else:
            return ret




    def _cbReadFile(self, files, l, directory, glob):
        if not isinstance(files, failure.Failure):
            if glob:
                l.extend([f for f in files if fnmatch.fnmatch(f[0], glob)])
            else:
                l.extend(files)
            d = directory.read()
            d.addBoth(self._cbReadFile, l, directory, glob)
            return d
        else:
            reason = files
            reason.trap(EOFError)
            directory.close()
            return l




    def _cbOpenList(self, directory, glob):
        files = []
        d = directory.read()
        d.addBoth(self._cbReadFile, files, directory, glob)
        return d


    def _ebNotADirectory(self, reason, path, glob):
        d = self.client.openDirectory(path)
        d.addCallback(self._cbOpenList, glob)
        return d


    def _remoteGlob(self, fullPath):
        print('looking up %s' % fullPath)
        head, tail = os.path.split(fullPath)
        print head, tail
        if '*' in tail or '?' in tail:
            glob = 1
        else:
            glob = 0
        if tail and not glob: # could be file or directory
            # try directory first
            d = self.client.openDirectory(fullPath)
            d.addCallback(self._cbOpenList, '')
            d.addErrback(self._ebNotADirectory, head, tail)
        else:
            d = self.client.openDirectory(head)
            d.addCallback(self._cbOpenList, tail)
        return d


    def _cbDisplayFiles(self, files, options):
        files.sort()
        if 'all' not in options:
            files = [f for f in files if not f[0].startswith('.')]
            #print files        #To display files in the folder
            #com="cmd /K echo %s" %files
            #os.system(com)
            #return files
            #print files
            #print 'Returned files'
        if 'verbose' in options:
            lines = [f[1] for f in files]
            #com="cmd /K echo %s" %lines
            #os.system(com)
            l =  '\n'.join(lines)
            print ('Returned list \n%s' %l)
            return lines

        else:
            lines = [f[0] for f in files]
        if not lines:
            return None
            print 'Return None'
        else:
            return '\n'.join(lines)
            print 'Returned list'


    def m_LSFolder(self, path):

        options = ['verbose']

        #path, rest = self._getFilename(rest)
        fullPath = path
        #if not path:
        #   fullPath = self.currentDirectory + '/'
        #else:
        #    fullPath = os.path.join(self.currentDirectory, path)
        d = self._remoteGlob(fullPath)
        d.addCallback(self._cbDisplayFiles, options)
        return d



    #---------------------------------------------------------------
    def _cbGetDone(self, ignored, rf, lf):
        log.msg('get done')
        rf.close()
        lf.close()
        #if self.useProgressBar:
        #self.transport.write('\n')
        return "Transferred %s to %s" % (rf.name, lf.name)


    def _getNextChunk(self, chunks):
        end = 0
        for chunk in chunks:
            if end == 'eof':
                return # nothing more to get
            if end != chunk[0]:
                i = chunks.index(chunk)
                chunks.insert(i, (end, chunk[0]))
                return (end, chunk[0] - end)
            end = chunk[1]
        #bufSize = int(self.client.transport.conn.options['buffersize'])
        bufSize = self.bufSize
        chunks.append((end, end + bufSize))
        return (end, bufSize)


    def _cbGetRead(self, data, rf, lf, chunks, start, size, startTime):
        if data and isinstance(data, failure.Failure):
            log.msg('get read err: %s' % data)
            reason = data
            reason.trap(EOFError)
            i = chunks.index((start, start + size))
            del chunks[i]
            chunks.insert(i, (start, 'eof'))
        elif data:
            log.msg('get read data: %i' % len(data))
            lf.seek(start)
            lf.write(data)
            if len(data) != size:
                log.msg('got less than we asked for: %i < %i' %
                        (len(data), size))
                i = chunks.index((start, start + size))
                del chunks[i]
                chunks.insert(i, (start, start + len(data)))
            rf.total += len(data)
        #if self.useProgressBar:
            # self._printProgressBar(rf, startTime)
        chunk = self._getNextChunk(chunks)
        if not chunk:
            return
        else:
            start, length = chunk
        log.msg('asking for %i -> %i' % (start, start+length))
        d = rf.readChunk(start, length)
        d.addBoth(self._cbGetRead, rf, lf, chunks, start, length, startTime)
        return d





    def _cbGetFileSize(self, attrs, rf, lf):
        if not stat.S_ISREG(attrs['permissions']):
            rf.close()
            lf.close()
            return "Can't get non-regular file: %s" % rf.name
        rf.size = attrs['size']
        #bufferSize = self.client.transport.conn.options['buffersize']
        bufferSize = self.bufSize
        #numRequests = self.client.transport.conn.options['requests']
        numRequests = self.Nrequest
        rf.total = 0.0
        dList = []
        chunks = []
        #startTime = self.reactor.seconds()
        startTime = reactor.seconds()

        print startTime
        for i in range(numRequests):
            d = self._cbGetRead('', rf, lf, chunks, 0, bufferSize, startTime)
            dList.append(d)
        dl = defer.DeferredList(dList, fireOnOneErrback=1)
        dl.addCallback(self._cbGetDone, rf, lf)
        return dl







    #==================Downloading file===========================   
    def m_GetFile(self, local_path, remote_path):


        lf = file(local_path, 'wb',0)                    #Creating of the local open file where to copy remote file
        d = self.client.openFile(remote_path, filetransfer.FXF_READ, {}) # 
        d.addCallback(self._cbGetOpenFile, lf)
        d.addErrback(self._ebCloseLf, lf)
        return d
    #============================================================
    #============================================================

    def _cbPutDone(self, ignored, rf, lf):
        lf.close()
        rf.close()
        #if self.useProgressBar:
        #    self.transport.write('\n')
        return 'Transferred %s to %s' % (lf.name, rf.name)



    def _cbPutWrite(self, ignored, rf, lf, chunks, startTime):
        chunk = self._getNextChunk(chunks)
        start, size = chunk
        lf.seek(start)
        data = lf.read(size)
        #if self.useProgressBar:
        #    lf.total += len(data)
        #    self._printProgressBar(lf, startTime)
        if data:
            d = rf.writeChunk(start, data)
            d.addCallback(self._cbPutWrite, rf, lf, chunks, startTime)
            return d
        else:
            return



    def _cbPutOpenFile(self, rf, lf):
        numRequests = self.Nrequest
        #if self.useProgressBar:
        #   lf = FileWrapper(lf)
        dList = []
        chunks = []
        startTime = reactor.seconds()
        for i in range(numRequests):
            d = self._cbPutWrite(None, rf, lf, chunks, startTime)
            if d:
                dList.append(d)
        dl = defer.DeferredList(dList, fireOnOneErrback=1)
        dl.addCallback(self._cbPutDone, rf, lf)
        return dl




    #====================Uploading File==========================
    def m_PutFile(self, local_path, remote_path):

        lf = file(local_path, 'rb')
        flags = filetransfer.FXF_WRITE|filetransfer.FXF_CREAT|filetransfer.FXF_TRUNC
        d = self.client.openFile(remote_path, flags, {})
        d.addCallback(self._cbPutOpenFile, lf)
        d.addErrback(self._ebCloseLf, lf)
        return d
```

Comment: This is a simple code I have written  to customize the twisted conch scripts for windows environment.